# Can't make object look at the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get my character to look at the player, but the character is looking the wrong way.
I know my code works just not the way I want it to.

Here is the code

```
public GameObject Player;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.LookAt(Player.transform);
}
```

I tried to add a float to make that should make it so he looks at the player but that clearly didn't work.
The float wound subtract -90 form where he was looking but I can't find a wat to make that work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPU7l.jpg

This image shows what happens to the character right now when I test the code.

Comment: The transform of the character is likely incorrect.  +Z axis is Forward in unity, +Y is up, +X is Right.  You can parent your character to a gameobject that is oriented correctly and attach the script to that object.

Comment: could you show this in your SceneView -> as @hijinxbassist mentioned most probably you will find that the blue `Z` axis of the character is indeed looking the correct way ... just your meshes within this object are rotated wrong

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the rotation of the object and define Quaternion variable name it for example offset and substract offset from current rotation finally run your game and adjust offset till you get the character look in the correct direction

Comment: Thx you everyone my problem is fixed! have a good rest of your day!